# Wifi disconnects frequently in Macbook Pro 13"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I am new to Macbook Pro and Mac OS X. I am experiencing irritating problem. My internet wifi gets disconnected frequently.

Is this a problem with my internet provider or Mac book pro? I bought MBP just two weeks back. I am worried wether I got the defective laptop or what?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same problem with my iMac (17" Early 2006). I didn't have a cordless mouse/keyboard neither a microwave oven. The iMac was less than a meter away from the base station, with a wall between them. I tried the usual steps of trying to identify a less used channel to no avail. After several months the problem went away. I could be that some neighbor had some equipment interfering, but at least 2 different PC notebooks didn't have the problem. I always thought that it was some new patch that fixed it: either a firmware update or the release of Leopard.

Answer (score 2):

If the network you're connecting to uses WEP encryption, try switching it to WPA. You might remember a similar issue around the launch of iPad 2.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have multiple entries in your Keychain for the same network.  Sometimes it will get confused, try to use the wrong password and fail to connect.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and call the *AppleCare* support to try to solve the problem. Here are the steps I performed:

- Renew the IP address via *System preferences... / Network / Advanced... / TCP/IP / Renew DHCP*
- Shut down my Mac
- Starting my Mac with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: I will update this post within the next week if it doesn't fix the problem since the *AppleCare*  support call me back the 03/10/2017.

Answer (score 0):

Could be several causes, but first one I'd check is interference from other local WiFi networks, or from other electrical devices in your home.

An app like [iStumbler](http://www.istumbler.net/) will let you check if there are any nearby WiFi networks broadcasting on the same channel as yours -- if there are, you can set your router to use a different channel and see if that helps.

Harder to pin down interference from other electrical devices, but in general, make sure your router is as far away from other potential sources of interference as possible -- that includes cordless phone base stations, microwave ovens etc. This is less of a problem now than it used to be, but it can still occasionally cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try your notebook on few other wifi networks.

If on all you get disconnects, probably your macbook is broken. If in others your connection is OK, your current wifi have problems, what can be:

- DSL disconnects (some routers drop wifi too, when got DSL disconnect)
- problems with wifi access point

  - try disable encryption - or try change encryption scheme
  - try tweak some setting in the access point (e.g. channel or soo)
  - try this command for get some info

    ```
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I
    ```
  - can also try change channel number with the above command (for the help, run it without arguments)

Other:

- stop microwave owen ;)